# MVC5 checkbox not cheked even "value = true"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5, I found there is a lot of problem about checkbox.

There is my code :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item 3" value="true">
```

But now there is even not any checkbox= **checked**.  Then user how know which is already select?

Another problem is if I checked it, the **value still not change**.....So how make sure the result is correct?

**Update 1:**
Sorry for the stupid question, early I search answer, but every one recommend use **value="true"**.  looks like change it to **checked="checked"** will fine.

Comment: How you manage a property named `Item 3`? Anyway an `<input>` of type `checkbox` isn't checked using `value` attribute but using `checked` attribute. No matters what you put in `value`, no one of your checkboxes will be checked.

Comment: Did you try setting the `checked` attribute of the `input` element?  What exactly isn't working?  It's not clear what you're asking, or what this HTML code has to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: The value of the checkbox is not suppose to change when checked. Checking the box tells the browser to submit the name/value pair when the form is submitted. Back in the old days, we used to include hidden fields with the same name as the checkbox so we'd at least get a name and default value on the server side.

Comment: If you are looking at the HTML with the HTML inspector in browser development tools, you will not see any change. The HTML is only what the server sends to the browser. Interactive changes are tracked in the DOM, but are not reflected back in the HTML.

Comment: Why are you not using Html.CheckBox() or Html.CheckBoxFor()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just HTML, try the following...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item 3" checked>
```

or, as pointed out...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Item 3" checked="checked">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc43uo2j/2/)

Comment: checked="checked" is also acceptable. Stricter for XHTML, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle checkboxes and always get a value on the server side (not only when it is checked)
consider also this solution:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="true" name="Item 3" @(condition ? "checked" : "")/>
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Item 3"/>
```

`value="true"` means that this value will be send to server when the form is submited

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, it is best practice to approach forms by creating a model, sending it to the view and using razor syntax to actually render the form.

**Your Model or ViewModel:** (This will be in your Models folder)

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class FormViewModel
    {
        public bool Item3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in your **controller**, you can decide if you'd like it to be true or false:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FormViewModel newForm = new FormViewModel() { Item3 = true; } //This will mark it as checked
    return View(newForm);
}
```

You then just use that **model you sent from the controller, in your view**:

```
@model Project.Models.FormViewModel
```

Which allows your to **create a form** using the variables in that Model/ViewModel:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Item3)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Item3)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

You then just use the controller to catch the model, handle the variable and do what you want with it.

It will make it much easier for you to handle the data this way. This link gives a decent tutorial on how to create a model, video and handle user input in a form with MVC Razor: [Getting Started with Razor View Engine in MVC 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639695/Getting-Started-with-Razor-View-Engine-in-MVC)

Comment: thanks, but because there is a lot of checkbox. so I think maybe I need use FormCollection get the param more easy for me.

Comment: @qakmak This method is actually ideal for having a lot of variables. You can loop through all the variables and display the check boxes without having to display them manually. It makes it more maintainable. If you'd like, I can show you can examples of how to do that? Also, **Thank you David Martin** for the edit, totally missed that one.

Comment: @qakmak, Follow Termato's advice here. Using `FormCollection` to get checkbox values is problematic because unchecked checkboxes do not post back. Your useng MVC so make use of its features, particularly strongly typed helpers and model binding.

Comment: thank you guys, but the Item3 is actually a dynamic generate name(from a menu id), real name is : "Item" + MenuModel.Id. So I think FormCollection will better than this. then I know which menu is lost, then delete, which menu is checked, then bind the menu id with role.

Comment: The advice given by @Termato and Stephen Muecke is sound, for your dynamic names you can create a ViewModel to support your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox has a boolean attribute "checked" that must be present to set the checkbox to checked state. If you want it to be unchecked, don't put the attribute at all. Also, setting "checked=true", "checked=false", "checked=whatever", always returns as checked.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="one" checked> Checked
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="two"> Unchecked
```